# Meaning of a dialog from max payne 3

Tags: max-payne-3

What could be the meaning of a dialog from max payne 3 ?
"These bastards made the NYPD look like the Hari Krishnas."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hare Krishnas are a Hindu religious organization that teaches peace and unity.  In the context of the dialog, it means that the NYPD didn't put up much of a fight against their attackers to the point where it looked like the NYPD didn't fight back at all.